# Crystal Report Record Number?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2008

i have special field record number 
how to ignore suppressed rows ? 
and keep serialize

```
No P.Mood Amount
1   Cash   300
2   Cash   200
3   Visa   200
5   Cash   210 
7   Visa   310
8   Cash   108
10  Visa   404
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a running total field. This field only counts printed (non supressed) rows.